# How to disable dis-select button on specific item (ng select multiple)

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have been using, this https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect, what i want is, i want to disable the dis select features to the selected item.

[image]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for this?

Comment: Hello John i will help with this please start a conversation with me

Comment: @harkeshkumar hey man, do you have any suggestions, on how to achieve this?

Comment: yes i use angular material multiselect in my project so i can help you with this

Comment: and please also tell me which version of angular are you using

Comment: @harkeshkumar angular 7, and im using form group

Comment: @johncramer if not done yet please start in conversation and i will help you

Comment: @harkeshkumar hi sirr, i have updated my questions, i dont know how to start conversation :(, new to this site